# insert data from one table and some hard code to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have to insert data from one table to another and also some hard code data to same table.
For Example:-

```
$value1 = "abc";
$value2 = "xyz";
mysql_query("insert into table1(name,address,state,city) select * from table2");
```

columns in table 1 is :-

name,address,state,city.

columns in table 2 is:-

name and address.

now i have to insert name and address from table 2 and state,city value from $value1 and $value2 to table 1 in single query.
I don't want use update query at 2nd time.

Please suggest me.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you have any other auto-incrementing column in any of the tables

Comment: try to add `echo mysql_errno() . ' - ' . mysql_error();` after your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("insert into `table 1`(name,address,state,city) select name,address, '$value1', '$value2' from table2");
```

Notice: mysql_* is deprecated

For debugging your queries you can use

```
echo mysql_errno() . ' - ' . mysql_error();
```

As @Rozklad mentioned, if you have whitespaces in table name and `table 1` is not an example name so you need to use **`** symbol

Comment: @Ushakov what do mean by mysql_* is depricated

Comment: @akki there is [big warning](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) on every page of mysql_* functions. It means, that some next release of PHP may remove this functions and code wich uses it will not work

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in your table name or typo, therefore use either these **`** to clarify the name of table, otherwise, the query seems okay as ushakov posted

```
mysql_query("insert into `table 1`(name,address,state,city) select name,address,'$value1','$value2' from table2");
```

Comment: Tell me what does var_dump( mysql_ping() ); say

Answer (score 0):

```
$value1 = "abc";
$value2 = "xyz";

$result=mysql_query(select * from table2);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

mysql_query("insert into table1(name,address,state,city) values('$row[name]','$row[address]','$value1','$value1')");
```

Comment: In this,we r using two query..is it possible in single query?